# getpeername can not recognize connection established

Tags: android, c

there's simple socket program (server / client) i made.
server is working on windows and client is android app which contains shared library made of c socket.

in client side, to avoid freeze i changed socket to NON_BLOCK than rollback to BLOCK socket after passing connect() function. after that, i search connection is available using getpeername().

as below...

```
flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags|O_NONBLOCK);

nRet = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
if (nRet < 0)
    if (errno != EINPROGRESS && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
        return ERR_CONN;

...
...

nRet = select(sock+1, &readset, &writeset, NULL, &tv);
if (nRet == 0)
    if (errno != EINPROGRESS && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
        return ERR_SELECT;

nRet = getpeername(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);
if (nRet != 0)
    return ERR_GETPEER;

fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags);
```

everything's working well. except working on 3G mode.

sometimes even if Server got connection, client side return errors in getpeername().
error code is ENOTCONN.

what should i implement to avoid this? any suggestion would be appreciate.
thx in advance.

---

i found what's wrong.

first, i should roll back to BLOCK socket after passing connect() not before return.
second, it seems that select() doesn't guarantee to hold for timeval, so i made function like GetTickCount() than counted time to break loop.

here's my solution.

```
fcntl(O_NONBLOCK);
connect();
fcntl(BLOCK);

while (true)
{
    fd_set rdfs, wdfs;
    FD_ZERO(&rdfs); FD_ZERO(&wdfs);
    FD_SET(sock, &rdfs); FD_SET(sock, &wdfs);

    tv.tv_sec = 0; tv.tv_usec = 100;
    nRet = select(sock + 1, &rdfs, &wdfs, NULL, &tv);
    if (nRet == -1) return -1;
    else if (nRet)
    {
        nRet = getpeername();
        if (!nRet)
            break;
    }

    if (get_tick_count() - delay > timeout)
        return -2;
}
```

thx! sarnold, caf :)

Comment: Did your `select(2)` actually return `sock` in the `readset`?

Comment: do you mean, did i checked FD_ISSET? sorry for my poor english :( if so, no it doesn't. i didn't check FD_ISSET before getpeername.

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly; you should only attempt read-like operations on sockets that appear in the `FD_ISSET(3)` for your `readset` output variable.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if the socket is connected, it is more usual to use `getsockopt()` rather than `getpeername()`:

```
int so_error;
socklen_t len = sizeof so_error;

getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &len);

if (so_error == 0) {
    /* socket is connected */
}
```